# Incorrect output when using filter RDD after broadcast join in PySpark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have my below PySpark code. I have provided the output in the comments for each action. For the sake of simplicity, I have not provided SparkSession commands below.
I am doing broadcast join (using customer_id as the key) considering customers.csv is a small dataset and orders.csv as the large dataset.

```
orders_base = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/orders/orders.csv")
# order_id,order_date,customer_id,order_status
# 1,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,11599,CLOSED

cust_base = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/customers/customers.csv")
# customer_id,Fname,Lname,State,ZipCode
# 1,Richard,Hernandez,TX,78521

orders_mapped = orders_base.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[0],int(x.split(",")[2])))

cust_mapped = cust_base.map(lambda x: int(x.split(",")[0]))
cust_broadcast_var = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(cust_mapped.collect())

order_cust_joined = orders_mapped.map(lambda x: (x[0],cust_broadcast_var.value[int(x[1])]))

orders_mapped.take(5)
# correct output: (order_id, customer_id)
# [(1, 11599), (2, 256), (3, 12111), (4, 8827), (5, 11318)]

order_cust_joined.take(5)
# When I run above command, it produces below incorrect output - (order_id, customer_id)
# [(1, 11600), (2, 257), (3, 12112), (4, 8828), (5, 11319)]
```

**Problem statement 1:** Not sure why +1 was done with all customer_ids

**Problem statement 2:** Also, if I try to use filter transformation to filter specific order_id=5 then I get below error:

```
order_cust_joined.filter(lambda x: x[0]==5).take(5)

#Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 14, w03.itversity.com, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 605, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 597, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(out_iter, outfile)
  File "/opt/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 271, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/opt/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1440, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "/opt/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/util.py", line 107, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-2-d323fe046ce6>", line 15, in <lambda>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone pls help?

Comment: Why do you need to use RDD APIs? It's much easier to use DataFrame API and don't parse the CSV "manually"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `cust_broadcast_var.value[int(x[1])]` part. x is each element of `orders_mapped`, which is something like `(1, 11599)`, so `x[1]` is `11599`. It means that you're trying to access the `11600th element` of `cust_broadcast_var.value`, which will lead to an `index out-of-range` error. You should use sth like `[int(x[0])-1]`

Below is your code but I print out the result for clarity

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


# create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('example').getOrCreate()

orders_base = spark.sparkContext.textFile("orders.csv")
print(orders_base.collect())
# ['1,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,11599,CLOSED', '2,2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,256,OPEN',

cust_base = spark.sparkContext.textFile("customers.csv")
print(cust_base.collect())
# ['1,Richard,Hernandez,TX,78521', '2,Mary,Barrett,CO,81144',

orders_mapped = orders_base.map(lambda x: (x.split(",")[0],int(x.split(",")[2])))
print(orders_mapped.collect())
# [('1', 11599), ('2', 256), ('3', 12111), ('4', 8827), ('5', 11318)]

cust_mapped = cust_base.map(lambda x: int(x.split(",")[0]))
print(cust_mapped.collect())
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

cust_broadcast_var = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(cust_mapped.collect())
print(cust_broadcast_var.value)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# You should use sth like [int(x[0])-1]
order_cust_joined = orders_mapped.map(lambda x: (x[0],cust_broadcast_var.value[int(x[0])-1]))

print(orders_mapped.take(5))
# correct output: (order_id, customer_id)
# [(1, 11599), (2, 256), (3, 12111), (4, 8827), (5, 11318)]

print(order_cust_joined.take(5))
# [('1', 1), ('2', 2), ('3', 3), ('4', 4), ('5', 5)]
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to refer int(x[1]-1) instead of x[0]-1. Below gives me correct results then:

order_cust_joined = orders_mapped.map(lambda x: (x[0],cust_broadcast_var.value[int(x[1])-1]))

But, does that mean broadcast_variable.value always refer to +1 index position?

Comment: @VaibhavGupta As I said x[1] will be something like 11599, 256,... and you won't have the index that high, so x[1] - 1 wont work either. There may be something wrong with your source data, or your posted code. Did you run the code you post in your question?

Comment: I ran the code with x[1] - 1 and it ran fine too

sample output:
order_cust_joined.take(5)
# [(1, 11599), (2, 256), (3, 12111), (4, 8827), (5, 11318)]

order_cust_joined.filter(lambda x: x[0]==5).take(5)
# [(5, 11318)]

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to implement this using the DataFrame APIs, and you'll get all benefits of automatic optimizations with automatic data broadcast, etc.

```py
# instead of inferSchema it's more efficient to provide schema explicitly
orders = spark.read.csv("customers.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
orders = spark.read.csv("orders.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
customers = spark.read.csv("customers.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
joined = orders.join(customers, "customer_id")
```

and you see result:

```
>>> joined.show()
+-----------+--------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
|customer_id|order_id|          order_date|order_status|  Fname|    Lname|State|ZipCode|
+-----------+--------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
|          1|       2|2014-07-25 00:00:...|        OPEN|Richard|Hernandez|   TX|  78521|
+-----------+--------+--------------------+------------+-------+---------+-----+-------+
```

And if you ask for the explanation, then you'll see customers dataframe is broadcasted automatically:

```
>>> joined.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [customer_id#44, order_id#42, order_date#43, order_status#45, Fname#67, Lname#68, State#69, ZipCode#70]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [customer_id#44], [customer_id#66], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Project [order_id#42, order_date#43, customer_id#44, order_status#45]
   :  +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(customer_id#44)
   :     +- FileScan csv [order_id#42,order_date#43,customer_id#44,order_status#45] Batched: false, DataFilters: [isnotnull(customer_id#44)], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/ott/development/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/orders.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(customer_id)], ReadSchema: struct<order_id:int,order_date:string,customer_id:int,order_status:string>
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, true] as bigint))), [id=#133]
      +- *(1) Project [customer_id#66, Fname#67, Lname#68, State#69, ZipCode#70]
         +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(customer_id#66)
            +- FileScan csv [customer_id#66,Fname#67,Lname#68,State#69,ZipCode#70] Batched: false, DataFilters: [isnotnull(customer_id#66)], Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/Users/ott/development/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/customers.csv], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(customer_id)], ReadSchema: struct<customer_id:int,Fname:string,Lname:string,State:string,ZipCode:int>
```